# Destructor of arrays of pointers in structures

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, structure

I have this structures and dynamically allocated arrays.
I can't use std::vector and std::string, because it is homework.

```
 struct Moves
    {
        const char* date;
        const char* street;
        const char* city;
    };

struct Data
{
    const char* id;
    const char* name;
    const char* surname;
    int count;
    Moves** moves;

};
```

I have a class, where I create a array of pointers on structure Data, where I dynamically allocate char* date, street, city.

Now, I need to delete these blocks of memory.
Well, I've tried this: ( Destructor of my class)
Question is: how should I free all allocated memory correctly?

```
class Reg
{
private:
 Data** arr;
 int counter;
public:
  Reg(){ arr=new Data*[1000]; }
  ~Reg();
  ... other methods
};

Reg::~Reg()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<arr[i]->count;c++)
            {
                delete arr[i]->moves;
            }

            delete arr[i];
        }

        delete [] arr;
    }
```

Here is an example of allocating:

```
arr[counter]=new Data; 
arr[counter]->id=new char[12];
arr[counter]->id=id;
arr[counter]->name=new char[strlen(name)+1];
arr[counter]->name=name;
arr[counter]->surname=new char[strlen(surname)+1];
arr[counter]->surname=surname;

arr[counter]->moves=new Moves*[100];
arr[counter]->moves[0]=new TMoves;

arr[counter]->moves[0]->city=new char[strlen(city)+1];
arr[counter]->moves[0]->city=city;

arr[counter]->moves[0]->date=new char[strlen(date)+1];
arr[counter]->moves[0]->date=date;

arr[counter]->moves[0]->street=new char[strlen(street)+1];
arr[counter]->moves[0]->street=street;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: arr is int? not int array?

Comment: It would be better to give each struct its own destructor (`Data()`, `~Moves`) and let them take care of themselves.

Comment: @Beta could you post your code here please?

Comment: Stop using pointers and use standard containers

Comment: There are so many things that could be wrong with the above code (and so many things that are) that it's very hard to answer the question. Need to see more code. In particular the '... other methods'. And I'll second what others are saying. Bugs or not you are trying to do this in completely the wrong way. Use std::string and std::vector and programming will get so much easier.

Comment: post edited, added examples

Answer (score 4):

Rather than try to address every problem in this code, I'll tell you a principle that for some reason is never taught in programming courses: **Start small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step and *never add to code that doesn't work.***

Look at this:

```
arr[counter]->moves[0]->city=new char[strlen(city)+1];
arr[counter]->moves[0]->city=city;
```

Even assuming that this Moves has been correctly constructed, **you allocate memory with `new` and then immediately abandon it, causing a memory leak.** Then *if* `city` (a variable with the same name as a member, not a good idea) is a pointer to a `char[]` on the heap, and *if* nothing bad is done with `city` for the rest of its lifetime, and *if* no other pointer to that array exists (or at least nothing bad is done with such a pointer) then this will not lead to undefined behavior. Do you feel that lucky?

Instead, consider this:

```
struct Moves
{
private:
  const char* city;

public:

  Moves()
  {
    city = NULL;
  }

  ~Moves()
  {
    if(city)
      delete [] city;
  }

  void setCity(const char ncity[])
  {
    if(city)
      delete [] city;
    char *temp = new char[strlen(ncity)+1];
    strcpy(temp, ncity);
    city = temp;
  }
};

...
arr[counter]->moves[0]->setCity(someCity);
```

Note that once `setCity()` is working correctly, invoking it from outside is clean, safe and simple. And once `Moves` is set up correctly, `Data` can be rewritten in a similar fashion, and then `Reg`.

And once you're used to this approach, you can learn to use `std::string`, and never muck around with `char[]` again.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this post, but here are a few suggestions:

- Consider using `std::vector` instead of arrays
- Consider using `std::string` instead of const char *
- Consider putting the destruction of the members of `struct Moves` and `struct Data` within those definitions

For example:

```
struct Moves
{
    const char* date;
    const char* street;
    const char* city;

    ~Moves () {
      delete [] date;
      ...
    }

};
```

Here's your `class Reg` using a `std::vector` to hold objects of type `Data *`:

```
class Reg
{
  private:
    std::vector<Data*> arr;
    int counter;  // this can probably be removed
  public:
    Reg() 
      :arr(1000, NULL) // initialize arr with 1000 NULL raw pointers
    {
    }

    ~Reg();
    ... other methods
};
```

A good C++ reference is [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/).

If you enhance your question you'll get some good answers (and learn a lot of C++) :-)

Comment: i've tried this, but valgrind says:

Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()

Comment: just read your update; if you cannot use vectors/strings, then my first question is:  does the "allocate" example compile for you?  I'm suspicious of this line:  `arr[counter]->id=id;`

Answer (score 0):

How much nicer is this?

```
struct Moves
{
  std::string date;
  std::string street;
  std::string city;
};

struct Data
{
  Data() { moves.reserve(1000); }
  std::string id;
  std::string name;
  std::string surname;

  typedef std::unique_ptr<Moves> MovesPtr;
  typedef std::vector<MovesPtr> MovesList;
  MovesList moves;
};
```

Now you can add new `Moves` and they will be released on destruction of the `Data` object.

```
int main()
{
  Data d;
  d.moves.push_back(Data::MovesPtr(new Moves()));

  return 0;
}
```

The STL is nice, is there to help you, and you should use it.